Brick forms with dynamic fields
In  Brick.Forms , the way to create a new form is that you have a Haskell data type with some pre defined fields which then become the corresponding input in the brick form.

This module provides an input form API. This API allows you to
construct an input interface based on a data type of your choice. Each
input in the form corresponds to a field in your data type. This API
then automatically dispatches keyboard and mouse input events to each
form input field, manages rendering of the form, notifies the user
when a form field's value is invalid, and stores valid inputs in your
data type when possible

I have a requirement where, I have, say a list of column names from a db table, and I want to make a brick form to insert a new row in the db table.
Since I could select any db table at run time, the column names can change at run time.
So at best the data type I can have is a thin wrapper around the list of column names.
How can I make brick form with such a data type?
For simplicity lets assume, the form ,for all the input fields rendered, accepts only string values or Text values.
If I cannot make a form with such a data type, what are the alternatives?

I took bricks FormDemo.hs, removed irrelevant bits and modified it from there. The code depends on containers and microlens-ghc. There might be a cleaner solution but this works.
Instead of using a record type like we normally do, we use a Map. The important part is at which gives a lens for our Map. One rather annoying drawback is that we end up with Maybe all over the place but I have a feeling that we can't get rid of it in a type-safe manner without dependent types.
Another difference with the original demo is our custom editMaybeTextField function which is needed to handle the Maybe values.
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main where

import Data.Text qualified as T
import Lens.Micro (Lens')

import Graphics.Vty qualified as V
import Graphics.Vty.Platform.Unix (mkVty)

import Brick
import Brick.Focus (
    focusRingCursor,
 )
import Brick.Forms (
    Form,
    FormFieldState,
    editField,
    focusedFormInputAttr,
    formFocus,
    formState,
    handleFormEvent,
    invalidFormInputAttr,
    newForm,
    renderForm,
    (@@=),
 )
import Brick.Widgets.Edit qualified as E
import Data.Map
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)
import Lens.Micro.GHC (at)

type FieldName = T.Text
type Properties = Map T.Text T.Text

makeFieldLens :: T.Text -> Lens' Properties (Maybe T.Text)
makeFieldLens = at @Properties

mkForm :: [FieldName] -> Properties -> Form Properties e (Maybe T.Text)
mkForm fieldNames =
    let label s w = padBottom (Pad 1) (vLimit 1 $ hLimit 15 $ txt s <+> fill ' ') <+> w
        createField :: FieldName -> Properties -> FormFieldState Properties e (Maybe T.Text)
        createField fieldName = label fieldName @@= editMaybeTextField (makeFieldLens fieldName) (Just fieldName) (Just 1)
     in newForm (fmap createField fieldNames)

editMaybeTextField ::
    (Ord n, Show n) =>
    Lens' s (Maybe T.Text) ->
    n ->
    Maybe Int ->
    s ->
    FormFieldState s e n
editMaybeTextField stLens n limit =
    let ini = fromMaybe ""
        val = Just . Just . T.intercalate "\n"
        renderText = txt . T.intercalate "\n"
     in editField stLens n limit ini val renderText id

theMap :: AttrMap
theMap =
    attrMap
        V.defAttr
        [ (E.editAttr, V.white `on` V.black)
        , (E.editFocusedAttr, V.black `on` V.yellow)
        , (invalidFormInputAttr, V.white `on` V.red)
        , (focusedFormInputAttr, V.black `on` V.yellow)
        ]

draw :: Form Properties e (Maybe T.Text) -> [Widget (Maybe T.Text)]
draw f = [renderForm f]

app :: App (Form Properties e (Maybe T.Text)) e (Maybe T.Text)
app =
    App
        { appDraw = draw
        , appHandleEvent = \ev -> do
            case ev of
                VtyEvent (V.EvKey V.KEsc []) -> halt
                _ -> handleFormEvent ev
        , appChooseCursor = focusRingCursor formFocus
        , appStartEvent = return ()
        , appAttrMap = const theMap
        }

getFieldNames :: IO [T.Text]
getFieldNames = pure ["something", "somethingelse"]

main :: IO ()
main = do
    fieldNames <- getFieldNames

    let buildVty = mkVty V.defaultConfig
        initialValues = fromList (fmap (,"") fieldNames)
        f = mkForm fieldNames initialValues

    initialVty <- buildVty
    f' <- customMain initialVty buildVty Nothing app f
    print $ formState f'


Could you tell me how you came up with this? like what was the thought process, because I read it and I thought may be I am stuck.

@kush87, I first set the form's type to what I wanted. I then parametrised mkForm with the field names. After that, I removed the static list of fields and replaced it with fmap and then I started making the createField function based on what was on the original example. After that, I just followed the types and that got me to the compiling program after some head-scratching. General tips: use typed holes, read carefully through the type errors and try to make sense of why the compiler wants what it wants, use type hints to turn type variables into concrete types.
